# Replace non-numeric characters with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the regular expression `/^\+(90)[2-5]{1}[0-9]{9}$/` for phone validation, but when someone enters any special characters (such as `*` `-` `/` `(` `)` `-` `_`) in the input, I want to replace the characters with an empty string (remove them). Note that I don't want to replace the `+`.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you provide and example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will remove all non-numeric characters in a given string:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,"");
```

`\D` matches anything that isn't a number; `\d` matches a number.

---

Misread the question. To remove all non-numeric characters except `+`, do:

```
myString = myString.replace(/[^\d\+]/g,"");
```

Comment: but I want only plus ( +) you know my phone number starts with +90

Comment: @psygnosis: Sorry, I misread your question. Just edited this answer with a solution that will keep + signs.

Comment: No need to escape `+` inside a character group.

Comment: thank you it worked if I use the same code line..with username only alphabet characters   myString.replace(/\W/g,"") is this work?

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = document.getElementById('phone');
input.onkeypress = function(){
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, '');
}
```