# remove space, -, () from phone number

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which are phone numbers such as:

`phoneArray = [{"phone": "+11 111 111"},{"phone": "+22 222 222"}]`

I did a loop on it to remove spaces because I want this result:

> [{"phone": "+11111111"},{"phone": "+22222222"}]

but I only could remove the first space which looked like

> [{"phone": "+11111 111"},{"phone": "+22222 222"}

with this code:

```
for(i=0 ; i<phoneArray.length ; i++) {

let test = phoneArray[i].phone.replace(" ","");
}
```

I actually have other phone numbers like {"phone": "(22) 222-222"} to format but if I can remove space I can remove other signes like ()- I think.

I don't use regex because I don't understand it yet.

Comment: you need to use the regex to replace all spaces: `.replace(/ /g,"")`

Comment: Turn it the other way around: you want to remove everything *but* numbers and "+"…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace nonNumeric characters with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097305/replace-nonnumeric-characters-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

To remove all characters except for `+` and numbers, you can do this:

```js
let p = "+1 (555) 555-555"

console.log(p.replace(/[^\d\+]/g,''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a regex pattern to your replace function. Like that:

```js
let p = "+(11) 111 111-11"

console.log(p.replace(/[\s\-\(\)]/g,''))
```

Comment: This only removes spaces, OP also wants dashes and parentheses removed

Answer (score 1):

I would use the map function to iterate the array and change each of the values, to each value will apply the function replace with a regex in order to remove the non digits number and +.

```js
phoneArray = [{"phone": "+11 111 111"},{"phone": "+22 222 222"}]
phoneArray = phoneArray.map(p => {
   return {
     phone: p.phone.replace(/[^+\d+]/g,"")
   }
})
console.log(phoneArray)
```

Comment: how to do this but my phone number in number data type not in string

Answer (score -3):

You can try phone.replace(/\D/g,'') this will replace all non-numeric characters and will give you the numbers, hope this helps.[image]